# How do I get the Test Accuracy for my LSTM in Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to test my test set on the trained algorithm and print the accuracy of the test.

My Data is Machine Data and Ive already tried all solutions I could find online for calculating and the printing my tests accuracy. Im working with Tensorflow 1.13. and Python 3 on a virtual machine. Ive got the Code from python programming.net and modified it for my data.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import  recall_score, precision_score
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators._sklearn
import accuracy_score
from tensorflow.contrib.metrics import f1_score
from tensorflow.python import keras
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn, rnn_cell
from DataPreprocessing import x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test
import numpy as np

hm_epochs = 30
n_classes = 328 
batch_size = int (8)
chunk_size = 3
n_chunks = 8
rnn_size = 128
size=len(x_train)
learning_rate=0.001
length=len(x_train)


x =  tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_chunks,    chunk_size])
y =  tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32)

def recurrent_neural_network(x):
    layer =    {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([rnn_size,n_classes])),
         'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_classes]))}


    x = tf.transpose(x, [1,0,2])
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, chunk_size])
    x = tf.split(x, n_chunks, axis=0)


    lstm_cell = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(rnn_size)
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

    output = tf.matmul(outputs[-1],layer['weights']) + layer['biases']

    return output

def lstm_neural_network(x):
    prediction = recurrent_neural_network(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.compat.v1.losses.mean_squared_error(prediction, y))
    optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)


    with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for i in range(int(length / batch_size)):
                start=i
                end=i+batch_size
                epoch_x = np.array(x_train[start:end])
                epoch_y = np.array(y_train[start:end])
                epoch_x = np.reshape(epoch_x, [-1, n_chunks, chunk_size])
                i, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y},)
                epoch_loss += c
                i=end
            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval(prediction, feed_dict={x:x_test, y:y_test}))

lstm_neural_network(x)
```

The last 4 lines are the ones where the problem should lay, as the rest works pretty fine.

The error it shows is: 
TypeError: eval() got multiple values for argument 'feed_dict'

Answer (score 1):

```
y =  tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32)

def recurrent_neural_network(x):
    layer =    {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([rnn_size,n_classes])),
         'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_classes]))}


x = tf.transpose(x, [1,0,2])
x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, chunk_size])
x = tf.split(x, n_chunks, axis=0)


lstm_cell = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(rnn_size)
outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

output = tf.matmul(outputs[-1],layer['weights']) + layer['biases']

return output

def lstm_neural_network(x):
    prediction = recurrent_neural_network(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.compat.v1.losses.mean_squared_error(prediction, y))
    optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())

    for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
        epoch_loss = 0
        for i in range(int(length / batch_size)):
            start=i
            end=i+batch_size
            epoch_x = np.array(x_train[start:end])
            epoch_y = np.array(y_train[start:end])
            epoch_x = np.reshape(epoch_x, [-1, n_chunks, chunk_size])
            i, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y},)
            epoch_loss += c
            i=end
        print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)

    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
    print('Acc
```

Comment: please give some details about what the code is doing, and your answer. inline comments would be useful too

Comment: Its analyzing the quality and the machine inputs in order to predict the expected quality

Comment: @vlemaistre thanks for trying to help me, but I thing the last line got missing. What did you plan on riding there ?

Comment: @project079 I didn't try to help you, I just indented the lines of code that weren't. Feel free to look at the modifications made by my edit by clicking on "edited Jul 17 at 14:31"